# How to get CMD/console encoding in C#

Tags: c#, console, cmd

I need to specify the correct codepage to pack the files with zip library. As I see, I need to specify console encoding (866 in my case).

```
 C:\Users\User>mode

 Status for device CON:
 ----------------------
     Lines:          300
     Columns:        130
     Keyboard rate:  31
     Keyboard delay: 1
     Code page:      866 <- I need to get this value in C# code
```

Console.OutputEncoding returns 1251, which is not what I need.

Thanks,

Alex

**Update 1:** Obviously, execute "mode" in cmd.exe and parse output should work but it seems too rude. I'm looking for .NET solution.

**Update 2:** The application is windows forms application, not a console app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *default* code page for a console mode app is determined by the system locale.  Control Panel + Region and Language, Administrative tab, Change System Locale.  Your Windows code page is Cyrillic, so is your console code page so there's a reasonable chance that this code will work:

```
        int lcid = GetSystemDefaultLCID();
        var ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lcid);
        var page = ci.TextInfo.OEMCodePage;
        // etc..

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetSystemDefaultLCID();
```

*Do* avoid writing code like this, 8-bit text encodings are a mine field.  There certainly isn't any decent reason to have to run a console-mode zip program, there are plenty of .NET zip libraries available.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`Encoding.CodePage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.codepage.aspx) property:

```
var codePage = Console.OutputEncoding.CodePage;
```

which will give you a code page value (866 in your example).

Comment: MessageBox.Show(Console.OutputEncoding.CodePage.ToString()) -> 1251. BTW, this is windows forms application, not a console app.

Answer (score 1):

for me 852 (Latin II):

```
Encoding consoleEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage);
```