# Incorrect display of characters in WPF

Tags: c#

I want to get some information from netsh.exe.

When I create a Console App with this code:

```
Process netshStarter = new Process();
netshStarter.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
netshStarter.StartInfo.Arguments = "interface show interface";

netshStarter.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
netshStarter.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

netshStarter.Start();

string output = netshStarter.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I get the correct characters: [image: 'output' variable.]

But when I start the same code in a WPF project, Cyrillic symbols from netsh display like this: [image: incorrectly]

I tried to encode this string, but there was no result.

```
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(output);
        output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); // also tried here "Default" instead UTF8
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Looks like you might want to set `StandardOutputEncoding` to something appropriate - but I don't know what encoding you should use.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/48436394/7535148

Comment: Jon Skeet, Andrew Rogers, thanks for your advices. I've tried `StandardOutputEncoding` before, but i used `1252` code as  parameter. Now I'm using `866` - and data is correct! Thank you very much!